# Rails 5, scope with agregation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, product and image.
Product has many images.
Each iemage has position field with number.

```
 Product
 id | name
 1  | Car

Image 
id| product_id| file_name | position
1 | 1         | asdad.jpg | 1
1 | 1         | asda.jpg  | 2
```

How to create scope to one image with trhe lowest position number?

```
scope :main_image, -> { ??? }
```

And than:

```
@product.main_image.image.url
```

Regards
Sssebaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need scope, you need method named `main_image`:

```
def main_image
  images.order(:position).first
end
```

Comment: Big thank you. Works perfect.  One extra question. Why not scope?

Comment: @sssebaaa scopes are supposed to return `ActiveRecord::Relation`, when you need something else - that's probably not a scope